# Using a Boolean method that never returns "false" to check user permissions

Tags: java, error-handling, exception, authorization

I need to check that a user is allowed to save/retrieve contacts to/from the database by calling a web service, and return an HTTP403 with an explanation if it is not the case.

So for the sake of factorizing the code, I decided to use a boolean method that "never" returns `false` and is there only to check this, and throws a corresponding exception.

```
public boolean canPerformAction(User authenticatedUser) throws ForbiddenActionException{
  if(authenticatedUser == null){
    throw new ForbiddenActionException("There must be a user to perform an action !");
  }

  if(!authenticatedUser.BelongToCompany(company)){
    throw new ForbiddenActionException("The user doesn't belong to the company, therefore he can't perform the action");
  }

  return true;
}
```

Then in `saveContact`, I call it as follows:

```
public Person saveContact(User user, Person contact) throws ForbiddenActionException{

  canPerformAction(user);

  contact= persistContact(contact);

  return contact;
}
```

I do the same thing in `retrieveContact`:

```
public Person retrieveContact(User user, String contactId) throws ForbiddenActionException{

    canPerformAction(user);

    return fetchContact(contactId);
 }
```

And finally these methods are called in the web service:

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response retrieveContact(@PathParam("contactId") String contactId) {
  try{
    Person contact= retrieveContact(getUser(), contactId);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(contact).build();
  }catch(ForbiddenActionException e){
    return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
  }
}

@POST
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response saveContact(@PathParam("id") String id, Person contact) {
  try{
    Person contact= saveContact(getUser(), contact);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(contact).build();
  }catch(ForbiddenActionException e){
    return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
  }
}
```

Do you think that this is an acceptable approach of dealing with the problem ?

Comment: Why not just make it `void` since you're not doing anything with the `true` value anyway?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Absolutely, `void` is more suitable in this case. 
But is it a good practice / common to put checks in `void` methods ? Won't it be consided as bad code ?

Comment: I'll defer to someone who's more familiar with Java to answer properly. I personally don't like it because it implies that the return value matters or should be used, which can confuse users. To me `void` signals that the function is run to execute commands. I'm specifically thinking of [Command Query Separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) when I say that.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan We'll wait then for the other users' opinions.
Thanks for your comments :)

Comment: Your braces don't match. Please ensure that you are posting real code, not code that has been sanitized for this question.

Comment: @200_success Fixed it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Question

The approach is acceptable and it's perfectly valid to use a method like `canPerformAction`. But it shouldn't return an unused `boolean` and can be `static`:

```
private static void ensureUserAuthorized(User user) throws ForbiddenActionException {
  if (user == null) {
    throw new ForbiddenActionException("message");
  }
  if (!user.belongsToCompany(company)) {
    throw new ForbiddenActionException("message");
  }
}
```

#### Other Stuff

The boilerplate response building instructions `return Response.status...` in service methods can be avoided in two ways:

1) Create an ad-hoc shortcut method like

```
private static Response buildResponse(Status status, Object entity) {
  return Response.status(status).entity(entity).build();
}
```

Or, better

2) If you are using [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net) behind your JAX-RS annotations, add an exception mapper class:

```
@Provider
public class ForbiddenActionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ForbiddenActionException> {

  @Override
  public Response toResponse(ForbiddenActionException ex) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN)
                   .entity(ex.getMessage())
                   .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                   .build();
  }
}
```

In this second case the service method can be shortened as follows:

```
@POST
@annotations...
public Contact saveContact(@PathParam("id") String id, Person contact) throws ForbiddenActionException {
  return saveContact(getUser(), contact);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer !! 
But I'd like to confirm something; I assume you meant that the service method should return `buildResponse(Response.Status.OK, saveContact(getUser(), contact)` instead of `saveContact(getUser(), contact)`once the response builder method `buildResponse` has been defined ?

Comment: If you keep the `Response` return type of the service method, the `try-catch` blocks should be kept and `return buildResponse(args);` can be used. Otherwise you can change the return type to `Contact` and use directly `return saveContact(args);` + add `throws` clause. In case of  exception, it will be intercepted by the framework and `ForbiddenActionMapper` will be used to build the 403 response.